# JSF 2.3 fails to support WebSocket with Tomcat 9

Tags: tomcat, jsf-2, jsf-2.3

I tried to test new WebSocket feature with JSF 2.3.3(Glassfish implementation). I used Tomcat 9.0.1 as web server and followed this guide(https://javaserverfaces.github.io/whats-new-in-jsf23.html)

I created a managed bean:

```
@Named
@ApplicationScoped
public class Controller {

    @Inject @Push
    private PushContext cityChannel;

    public void send() {
        cityChannel.send("test");
    }
}
```

updated index.xhtml:

```
<f:websocket channel="cityChannel"
            onmessage="function(message){alert(message)}" />
```

And updated web.xml:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.ENABLE_CDI_RESOLVER_CHAIN</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.ENABLE_WEBSOCKET_ENDPOINT</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
</context-param>
```

Unfortunately Tomcat failed to load application with an error:

```
SEVERE [main] com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener.contextInitialized Critical error during deployment:
 javax.websocket.DeploymentException: Multiple Endpoints may not be deployed to the same path [/javax.faces.push/{channel}] : existing endpoint was [class com.sun.faces.push.WebsocketEndpoint] and new endpoint is [class com.sun.faces.push.WebsocketEndpoint]
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsServerContainer.addEndpoint(WsServerContainer.java:169)
```

If I remove context param javax.faces.ENABLE_WEBSOCKET_ENDPOINT then JSF runtime raises an error when I hit index.xhtml:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: f:websocket endpoint is not enabled. You need to set web.xml context param 'javax.faces.ENABLE_WEBSOCKET_ENDPOINT' with value 'true'.
```

Please, advise.

Comment: Probably see https://github.com/javaserverfaces/mojarra/issues/4305

Comment: @Sergey did you find any solution for this issue? I am facing same issue while using jsf 2.3 and primefaces(6.1, 6.2) if enable websocket

Answer (score 2):

> javax.websocket.DeploymentException: Multiple Endpoints may not be deployed to the same path [/javax.faces.push/{channel}] : existing endpoint was [class com.sun.faces.push.WebsocketEndpoint] and new endpoint is [class com.sun.faces.push.WebsocketEndpoint]
>           at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsServerContainer.addEndpoint(WsServerContainer.java:169)
>   I

This will happen when the runtime classpath is polluted with multiple Mojarra implementations. For example, one coming from a `jsf-impl.jar` file and another coming from a `javax.faces.jar` file. Or perhaps even multiple different versioned one.

You need to ensure that you have only one version of a library in the runtime classpath. This does not apply specifically to Mojarra, but to every Java based library.

Installation instructions of Mojarra can be found in its [README](https://github.com/javaserverfaces/mojarra/blob/master/README.md).